# Syntax error on token ")", delete this token

Tags: jsp

```
var name = '<%=((HouseHoldDetails)session.getAttribute("houseDetails")).getFirstName()%>';
```

What is syntactically wrong with above line of code. I am getting a syntax error mentioned in title in eclipse.

Comment: Is your jsp working as expected?

Comment: Is that the full error message?  If not, post the entire thing.

Comment: No tried to run it got an "An exception occurred processing JSP page /xxx.jsp at line xxx"

Comment: Can you give a complete stackTrace of the error?

Comment: Why are you using scriptlets in the first place. They shouldn't be used. For years and years. Learn the JSP EL: `${houseDetails.firstName}`

Comment: @SurrealDreams, the error mssage shown in title is the only and complete error message that i get.

Comment: the error given by eclipse on jsp validation is not acccurate, you should look to the server console or the jsp when it's rendered on browser!

Comment: I solved the problem changed the code as follows <%HouseHoldDetails house = (HouseHoldDetails)session.getAttribute("houseDetails"); %>
<% String username = house.getFirstName(); %>
and

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, changed the code as follows

```
<%HouseHoldDetails house = (HouseHoldDetails)session.getAttribute("houseDetails"); %>
<% String username = house.getFirstName(); %>
```

and then

```
<p ><%="Hi! "+ username %></p>
```